# How can I count all cells in a row based on the value in a column in MS Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

It's hard to word this correctly, so I'll try to describe it better here.

I have a spreadsheet:

[image: http://imgur.com/XmxG65f]

(this is a very simplified version I just made to illustrate what I'm after).

Each person has an X under either Dog or Cat (it doesn't have to be X though, all I care about is counting non-blank cells). I would like to count the number of X under Cat, and the number of X under Dog for each user, and fill in that count in the lower table, but not simply count the total number of X in each person's row. So, the formula I'm after would show 2 under Cat and 0 under Dog for Alice, 1 under Cat and 2 under Dog for Bob, etc.

I've tried using COUNTA, but I can't figure out how to make it only count things where the matching cell at the top is DOG or CAT.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend here is [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842). This gives you the ability to check multiple ranges and criteria, if met it is counted. The proper syntax is as follows;

```
COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)
```

So, you will want to use make your `criteria_range1` to be `$B$1:$J$1`. We use the `$` to make the address absolute since the header row will stay the same. Then make the `criteria1` to be `$B$11` to reference the cell with "Cat". Then make `criteria_range2` to be `B2:J2`. No `$` are used because we are going to tell Excel do some work for us. Make `criteria2` to be `"x"`. Your formula in cell B12 should look like the following.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$J$1, $B$11, B2:J2, "x")
```

Now drag the lower right corner of this cell down the rest of the cells for the other names. If your sheet is not set to automatically calculate, press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

You should be able to reconstruct this formula to count the dogs.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I've already modified it to match my actual requirement, and it looks like it is good to go.